# TypeError: ApplicationServiceMock.application$.pipe is not a function

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-test

I'm trying to unittest a Angular 7 component which has this in the constructor

```
constructor(private store: ApplicationService) {
        this.store.application$.pipe(first()).subscribe(r => { this.application = r; });
    }
```

Now when I try to test I get the error

```
TypeError: ApplicationServiceMock.application$.pipe is not a function
```

This is how I try to test

```
const ApplicationServiceMock= mock(ApplicationService);
```

.....

```
when(ApplicationServiceMock.application$.pipe()).thenResolve(Observable.of(Applications.ApplicationServiceDummy));
```

.....

```
providers: [
                    { provide: ApplicationService, useFactory: () => ApplicationServiceMock}
                ],
```

I also tryed to use jasmine.spy, but even this is not working and throwing the exact same error. What am I doing wrong or missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what `mock` does. But I would assume it only creates an empty wrapper for your ApplicationService. You need to tell your spy or mock, that is does have a property called `application$` which returns any observable.

So you would need something like this:

```
const applicationServiceMock = {
  application$: () => EMPTY
}

describe('AppComponent', () => {
    let component: AppComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<AppComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [AppComponent],
            providers: [{provide: ApplicationService, useValue: applicationServiceMock}],
            schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
        })
            .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
    });

    it('should be created', () => {
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

Since you are accessing the observable inside the component's constructor you need to define the expected Observable either with `EMPTY` like I did or with `of(YOUR_TEST_VALUE_HERE)` inside the mock-property beforehand because the constructor gets called before you can intervene inside the  `it` block.

If you like to use `spyOn` you would need to move the subscription code from the component's constructor to the `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook. Then you can alter the stub and `spyOn` before you call the first fixture.detectChanges() inside your test.